# Keep latest file and delete all other

Tags: python

In my folder there are many pdf files with date-timestamp format such as shown in the last.
I would like to keep the latest file for the day and delete the rest for that day. How can I do in Python ?

```
2012-07-13-15-13-27_1342167207.pdf
2012-07-13-15-18-22_1342167502.pdf
2012-07-13-15-18-33_1342167513.pdf
2012-07-23-14-45-12_1343029512.pdf
2012-07-23-14-56-48_1343030208.pdf
2012-07-23-16-03-45_1343034225.pdf
2012-07-23-16-04-23_1343034263.pdf
2012-07-26-07-27-19_1343262439.pdf
2012-07-26-07-33-27_1343262807.pdf
2012-07-26-07-51-59_1343263919.pdf
2012-07-26-22-38-30_1343317110.pdf
2012-07-26-22-38-54_1343317134.pdf
2012-07-27-10-43-27_1343360607.pdf
2012-07-27-10-58-40_1343361520.pdf
2012-07-27-11-03-19_1343361799.pdf
2012-07-27-11-04-14_1343361854.pdf
```

Should I use list to fill and sort out then ? Desired output is:

```
2012-07-13-15-18-33_1342167513.pdf
2012-07-23-16-04-23_1343034263.pdf
2012-07-26-22-38-54_1343317134.pdf
2012-07-27-11-04-14_1343361854.pdf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list and delete files if the next file in the list is on the same day,

```
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob("*.pdf")
files.sort()

for ifl, fl in enumerate(files[:-1]):
    if files[ifl+1].startswith(fl[:10]):    #Check if next file is same day
        os.unlink(fl)                       # It is - delete current file
```

**Edit:**

As the OPs question became clearer it became evident that not just the last file of the list is required, but the latest file of each day - to achieve this I included a "same day" conditioned unlinking.

Comment: this is not correct code. For your ref, I have edited question for better understanding.

Comment: @Shilpi - this should work now - I added in a day change detection condition.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet works with the test case given.

```
files = os.listdir(".")
days = set(fname[8:10] for fname in files)

for d in days:
    f = [i for i in files if i[8:10] == d]
    for x in sorted(f)[:-1]:
        os.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired list can also be achieved using groupby .

```
from itertools import groupby
from os import listdir,unlink

filtered_list = list()
names = os.listdir()

for key,group in groupby(names,lambda x : x[:10]): # groups based on the start 10 characters of file
  filtered_list.append([item for item in group][-1]) #picks the last file from the group

print filtered_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way.  The following code is untested, but may work:

```
import os

names = os.listdir()
names.sort()
for f in names[:-1]:
    os.unlink(f)
```

Fortunately your file names use ISO8601 date format so the textual sort achieves the desired result with no need to parse the dates.

Comment: it removes all pdf files in that directory

Comment: The `[:-1]` slice should omits the last item from the list in the iteration.  However, I did assume the directory contains no other files.  If it did, then the other file may be the only one left.  Another answer used `glob('*.pdf')` to list only the PDF files instead of all files in the directory.

Answer (score -1):

Using dictionary You can keep one value. This can be dirty and quickest solution, maybe not the best.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import datetime
import stat
import shutil

filelist=[]
lst=[]
dc={}

os.chdir(".")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
        lst.append(files)

for x in lst:
    print x[0:10].replace("-","")
    dc[int(x[0:10].replace("-",""))]=x

a = dc.items()
flist=[]
for k, v in a:
    flist.append(v)

dir="tmpdir"    
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)

from shutil import copyfile
for x in flist:
    print x
    copyfile(x, dir + "/" + x)

#os.chdir(".")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
            os.unlink(files)

os.chdir("./tmpdir")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
        copyfile(files, "../"+files)

os.chdir("../")
shutil.rmtree(os.path.abspath(".")+"/tmpdir")
```

Comment: Um... I'm not sure what this code is meant to do, but I think it's overcomplicating the problem a little =)