# Find duplicate filenames, and only keep newest file using python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have +20 000 files, that look like this below, all in the same directory:

```
8003825.pdf
8003825.tif
8006826.tif
```

How does one find all duplicate filenames, while ignoring the file extension.

Clarification: I refer to a duplicate being a file with the same filename while ignoring the file extension. I do **not** care if the file is not 100% the same (ex. hashsize or anything like that)

For example:

```
"8003825" appears twice
```

Then look at the metadata of each duplicate file and only keep the newest one.

Similar to this post:

[Keep latest file and delete all other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732465/keep-latest-file-and-delete-all-other)

I think I have to create a list of all files, check if file already exists. If so then use os.stat to determine the modification date?

I'm a little concerned about loading all those filename's into memory. And wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing things...

Python 2.6
Windows 7

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned about loading 20,000 or even 200,000 filenames into memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with `O(n)` complexity. The solutions with `sort` have `O(n*log(n))` complexity.

```
import os
from collections import namedtuple

directory = #file directory
os.chdir(directory)

newest_files = {}
Entry = namedtuple('Entry',['date','file_name'])

for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    cashed_file = newest_files.get(name)
    this_file_date = os.path.getmtime(file_name)
    if cashed_file is None:
        newest_files[name] = Entry(this_file_date,file_name)
    else:
        if this_file_date > cashed_file.date: #replace with the newer one
            newest_files[name] = Entry(this_file_date,file_name)
```

`newest_files` is a dictonary having file names without extensions as keys with values of named tuples which hold file full file name and modification date. If the new file that is encountered is inside the dictionary, its date is compared to the stored in the dictionary one and it is replaced if necessary.

In the end you have a dictionary with the most recent files.

Then you may use this list to perform the second pass. Note, that lookup complexity in the dictionary is `O(1)`. So the overall complexity of looking all `n` files in the dictionary is `O(n)`.

For example, if you want to leave only the newest files with the same name and delete the other, this can be achieved in the following way:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    cashed_file_name = newest_files.get(name).file_name
    if file_name != cashed_file_name: #it's not the newest with this name
        os.remove(file_name)
```

---

As suggested by **Blckknght** in the comments, you can even avoid the second pass and delete the older file as soon as you encounter the newer one, just by adding one line of the code:

```
    else:
        if this_file_date > cashed_file.date: #replace with the newer one
            newest_files[name] = Entry(this_file_date,file_name)
            os.remove(cashed_file.file_name) #this line added
```

Comment: +1 Nice! it only keeps in memory the files it need and is O(n).

Comment: You can even get away with doing just one pass. Each time you compare a file's age with a cached one, immediately delete whichever file is older. At the end of the single pass you'll only have the newest files left for each name.

Answer (score 2):

First, get a list of file names and sort them.  This will put any duplicates next to each other.

Then, strip off the file extension and compare to neighbors, [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) may be useful here.

Once you have grouped the duplicates, pick the one you want to keep using `os.stat()`.

In the end your code might looks something like this:

```
import os, itertools

files = os.listdir(base_directory)
files.sort()
for k, g in itertools.groupby(files, lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[0]):
     dups = list(g)
     if len(dups) > 1:
         # figure out which file(s) to remove
```

You shouldn't have to worry about memory here, you're looking at something on the order of a couple of megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

For the filename counter you could use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that stores how many times each file appears:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
for file_name in file_names:
   file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0]
   counter[file_name] += 1
```

Comment: The files in a directory are going to be sorted, why would he want to count them?

Comment: @kreativitea Because quoting from: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir - `Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.`

Comment: Yes, but i mean you would use `sorted(os.listdir(directory))`, and avoid creating an entirely new dictionary. iterating over a sorted list, creating a list of files with the same name, scanning the group, and resetting the chain seems significantly more efficient.