# Search for similar duplicate filenames (differs the datestamp at end of filename)

Tags: linux, bash, duplicates, filenames

I have a similar (almost the same) problem like ([Keep latest file and delete all other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732465/keep-latest-file-and-delete-all-other))
 except that my file list differs and I don't know Python (trying to do it in Bash)

the directories contain files like this for example:

```
mysql-2016-01-24/     *<--  dirname*
    adsoglasi-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    adsoglasi-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    adsoglasi-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    adsoglasi-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    adsoglasi-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    ehoplit-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    ehoplit-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    ehoplit-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    ehoplit-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    ehoplit-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    posavje-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    posavje-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    posavje-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    posavje-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    posavje-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-05.35.log
    export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-09.35.log
    export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-13.35.log
    export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-17.35.log
    export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-21.35.log
    flora-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    flora-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    flora-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    flora-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    flora-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    karcher-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    karcher-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    karcher-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    karcher-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    karcher-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    knjigarna-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    knjigarna-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    knjigarna-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    knjigarna-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    knjigarna-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    mysql-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    mysql-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    mysql-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    mysql-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    mysql-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-05.36.49.gz
    mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-09.36.50.gz
    mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-13.36.48.gz
    mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-17.36.48.gz
    mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-21.36.49.gz
    pohistvo-2016-01-24-05.35.gz
    pohistvo-2016-01-24-09.35.gz
    pohistvo-2016-01-24-13.35.gz
    pohistvo-2016-01-24-17.35.gz
    pohistvo-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
    akord-2016-01-24-05.36.gz
    akord-2016-01-24-09.36.gz
    akord-2016-01-24-13.36.gz
    akord-2016-01-24-17.36.gz
    akord-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
    ekomprof-2016-01-24-05.36.gz
    ekomprof-2016-01-24-09.36.gz
    ekomprof-2016-01-24-13.36.gz
    ekomprof-2016-01-24-17.36.gz
    ekomprof-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
    gume-2016-01-24-05.36.gz
    gume-2016-01-24-09.36.gz
    gume-2016-01-24-13.36.gz
    gume-2016-01-24-17.36.gz
    gume-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
    orchestra_test-2016-01-24-05.36.gz
    orchestra_test-2016-01-24-09.36.gz
    orchestra_test-2016-01-24-13.36.gz
    orchestra_test-2016-01-24-17.36.gz
    orchestra_test-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
```

and this is done every day in the separate dirs

```
mysql-2015-11-16/
mysql-2015-11-19/

-- || --

mysql-2016-01-18/
mysql-2016-01-19/
mysql-2016-01-20/
mysql-2016-01-21/
mysql-2016-01-22/
mysql-2016-01-23/
mysql-2016-01-24/
...
```

What I'm looking for that directories will **keep only the latest  date&time filenames** , and every "duplicate" similar files deleted (they clutter the space),

the output I wish to get:

```
mysql-2015-11-16/
                adsoglasi-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                ehoplit-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                posavje-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                export-mysql-baze-2016-01-16-21.35.log
                flora-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                karcher-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                knjigarna-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                mysql-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-16-21.36.49.gz
                pohistvo-2016-01-16-21.35.gz
                akord-2016-01-16-21.36.gz
                ekomprof-2016-01-16-21.36.gz
                gume-2016-01-16-21.36.gz
                orchestra_test-2016-01-16-21.36.gz
-- || --
mysql-2015-11-19/
                ....filenames with date ...2015-11-19... 
-- || --
mysql-2016-01-24/
                adsoglasi-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                ehoplit-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                posavje-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                export-mysql-baze-2016-01-24-21.35.log
                flora-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                karcher-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                knjigarna-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                mysql-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                mysqlshow_grants-2016-01-24-21.36.49.gz
                pohistvo-2016-01-24-21.35.gz
                akord-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
                ekomprof-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
                gume-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
                orchestra_test-2016-01-24-21.36.gz
```

... now ain't that a nicer list :-)

But since I didn't have any success with some "tools" like fdupes or similar, I'm asking for help from pros.

TY,
Best Regards.

Comment: Why are there multiple `export-mysql-baze`? Doesn't the "only the latest" rule apply here?

Comment: @Benjamin W. : ... it should, I was manually editing (deleting) the lines. List corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily those date-stamps are in ISO notation, with year-month-day, so that simply ascii sorted, is also date-sorted.  That makes things like these easy.  Just relying on the "ls" sorting gets the files in the correct order, which we can then read, compare the part before the date, and if previous one had the same base-part, then we can remove that previous one.

Assuming that indeed all the files inside those folder have that pattern (especially if no "dash-year-dash" pattern exists in the base-name part -- if not sure, you'll have to make the regex longer to be sure to match only the date+sequence+extension).  First let's see what would be removed, execute inside such a folder:

```
ls | perl -nle '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; print $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

To really remove those files just replace the "print" with the "unlink" statement:

```
ls | perl -nle '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; unlink $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

And to do that on all those folders, cd into the parent folder having all those mysql-YYYY-MM-DD folders:

```
for d in mysql*; do (cd $d;
    ls | perl -nle '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; unlink $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
); done
```

-- EDIT --

Apparently you have aliases "ls" to "ls -l".  To avoid "ls" completely:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort | perl -0x00 -ne '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; unlink $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

But when you're not even sure that all the files you feed as input there are not in the expected format, then maybe you should be way more specific in what files to handle, and what files to exclude.  Now the pattern assumes that the pattern "-2\d\d\d-" (dash, number 2, followed by 3 more numbers, followed by a dash) must be present in the filename, and that part starts the datestamp.

E.g. to match a full date in format '-YYYY-MM-DD-' (including dash before an after), and as far to the end of the name as possible;

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort | 
perl -0x00 -ne '($b)=m{^(.*)-2\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-.*}; unlink $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

Anything before that date is considered the base to compare; that date and stuff after is considered the "fuzzy" part and only used to sort.

Comment: You don't want or need `ls` here. The shell will expand any wildcard into alphabetical order. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @tripleee :     using "find":  
find ./ -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort |  perl -nle '($b) ...    it looks promising as I get some output.

Answer (score 0):

@PBI:

Unfortunately, this

```
ls | perl -nle '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; print $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

does not produce any output wanted (this is the actual output):

```
total 569356
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Jan 17 21:36 ./
```

The "ls" output :

```
--  || --
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root  22247827 Jan 17 05:35 akord-2016-01-17-05.35.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root  22266602 Jan 17 09:35 akord-2016-01-17-09.35.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root  22287951 Jan 17 13:35 akord-2016-01-17-13.35.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root  22248103 Jan 17 17:35 akord-2016-01-17-17.35.gz
--  || --
```

prints out at the beginning of the lines the filesizes and owner, which confuses Perl for sorting the filenames.

But ... the "find" command prints out nicely what expected to:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort | perl -nle '($b)=m{^(.*?)-2\d\d\d-.*}; print $fn if $fn && $b eq $p_b; $p_b=$b; $fn=$_;'
```

.

```
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-05.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-09.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-13.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-17.35.gz
```

what is exactly what it should print out, as opposed to the "source" list:

```
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-05.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-09.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-13.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-17.35.gz
adsoglasi-2015-12-17-21.35.gz
```

Now the last file is omitted (yaaay :-)  and thus it produces the list of files to be deleted ! Very nice !

**Important note !**

"find ..." without "**sort**" also doesn't output nothing useful, except one filename which remains in Perl "buffer" (as far as I understand it)

Comment: You have aliased "ls" to "ls -l" then.
To avoid using the alias, do "\ls"

Comment: Indeed, "\ls" does the job (btw, who doesn't alias the "ls" :-)